# Safari Scrollbar in iFrame Not showing for iPad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, safari

I have a page with iframe in it and as its long users need to scroll in iframe to see other content . Although iPad doesnt show any scrollbar which is by default as I think.Although I did read that you can scroll with two finger but that didnt work for me either .

Whats a possible solution in this case ? Show a div with jquery if its ipad which can scroll to a next location on page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem in one of my applications as well. Unfortunately mobile safari does not support scrollbars. You should be able to scroll using two fingers, though. In fact, the [iPad User Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/ipad_2_user_guide.pdf) explicitly calls this out:

> Use two fingers to scroll within a frame on 
>   a webpage. Use one finger to scroll the 
>   entire webpage

Alternatively, you could think about changing your page navigation. For example, if you are displaying a table of information you could use a pager to only show N items at a time. That would allow a user to page through your data without requiring a scrollbar.